# How to find and highlight duplicate rows based on 3 columns

Tags: excel, vba

does anyone have VBA code to highlight duplicate rows based on three columns?

I'm using a sheet called "Billing Voucher (Part 1)" I would like to create a button that highlights duplicate rows in blue (only based on three columns) when pressed.

For example,

```
   | D   E   I
---+-------------
 1 | 1   1   1
 2 | 1   2   7
 3 | 7   9   1
 4 | 1   1   1
```

Based on the above, the program should highlight row 1 and 4.

I'm not sure why is it so difficult to find the right code to highlight duplicates.

I cant use conditional formatting because it slows my computer tremendously, 
and a lot of the reusable code seems to either be overly complex, or does something else.

I've seen so many instances of code, isn't there a simple way to create the program without being overly complex

Comment: Why vba, Conditional Formatting will do it.

Comment: I've tried using conditional formatting, and it absolutely works. The problem i'm having is that it makes my worksheet extremely slow.

Comment: I'm not sure VBA being faster than conditional formatting.

Comment: What was the formula you used for conditional formatting?

Answer (score 0):

No strict need for VBA ...

1. create one more column as the concatenation of all key fields
2. sort the concatenation column
3. create a dup-check formula in yet another column (looking for equality in the row above) - like so:

[image]

all rows with result > 1 are the nth repetitions of the key.

After elimination of duplicates (or whatever processing) you can restore the original sort order by sorting on SortKey

Comment: Thank You Mike. I still incur slow processing by adding formulas. It seems when I add formulas, there is a lag when entering data within each field.